# Clicking sound. Revs decrease and increase

Tags: toyota, corolla, surging

I just bought a 2nd hand 2004 Corolla and am worried it's a lemon. When idling the engine feels like it going to lose power and the revs go down, then there's a clicking sound and the revs increase. Is this normal? There are no check engine lights but I am having issues with the indicators,  which I would say is unrelated

Comment: Is the air conditioning turned on?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  A hunting idle to me means either the idle air control (IAC) or the exhaust gas recirculation (EGR) valve is having issues. You don't state whether there are any codes (check engine light is on) or even what year/engine your corolla is ... could you please edit your question and put more pertinent information about your vehicle?

Comment: It's a 2004 Corolla. Yes the air conditioning has been on. Noe there's no check engine light on

Comment: I turned the air con off and when I did, the issue seemed a lot better.  When I turned the air con on, it immediately makes the same clicking sound once and then goes back to doing it intermittently

Comment: Could be any number of things, fluctuating revs could be your IAC, or a stuck open valve, air leak, fuel regulator... clicking could be the internal fan, the piston ring(s), a valve, a broken timing chain tensioner (does it go away when it warms up).... after thinking about it, I bet it's your a/c actuator that opens the door, the internals are made of plastic gears and they easily break... but they're simple to check and change